# Error executing command4 ' returned non-zero ex it status 127. Error executing command5: Command 'airflow db check' returned non-zero exit status 127

Tags: airflow-webserver

I am using apache airflow in standalone mode with local executor with default setting and backend database is postgre.

The server i am using for airflow having sufficient resources 1Tb memory and 60 CPU cores.

But airflow will be shutdown after some time may be few hours or after one/two days by throwing below error.

> error executing command4: Command ' airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$(hostname)" ' returned non-zero exit status 127.
> Error executing command5: Command 'airflow db check' returned non-zero exit status 127.

Could anyone please suggest the solution on this issue?